# Valid single character with dot at regex end

Tags: c#, regex

I need to realize the following regex:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9_]+.
```

Now I can't figure out why "**1**" or "**a**" is not valid.

In addition, the following examples:

```
 abc_123_1 
 _____abc___301 
 1 
 a
```

Should be **valid**, too.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Is the '.' part of the regular expression, or just a full stop at the end of the sentence?

Comment: Clarification, is your regex pattern: `[a-zA-Z0-9_]+.` or `[a-zA-Z0-9_]+` ? (i.e., does it have the `.` at the end?)

Comment: Someone has edited the question to remove the dot from the regex, but the question title states "with dot at regex end" so I believe it was meant to be part of the expression.

Comment: I added the dot again for the question, but let it off for the solution. Thank your for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note: based on the title of the question, I'm assuming that the expression you are using is `[a-zA-Z0-9_]+.` (at the time of writing, the question has been edited by someone other than the OP to remove that dot).

Your regex currently requires "at least one of a-z, A-Z, 0-9 or _", followed by "exactly one of any character". Therefore, it requires at least two characters to match.

The string "1" and "a" have only one character, and therefore do not match. Given your valid examples, are you sure you need that dot at the end?

The expression `[a-zA-Z0-9_]+` (without the dot) would match all your examples, including single character ones.

Comment: But `+` is for "one or more matches", isn't it?

Comment: @MartinR The + is for the first bit of the regex. The dot at the end then requires one additional character.

Comment: @martin-r the `.` after the `+` is "Exactly one of any character"

Comment: You are right, the question title says *"... with dot at regex end"*. I did not see the dot as part of the regex but as end of the sentence :-)

Comment: It seems that the regulation contains an error, because a single character should be possible. I let off the dot now. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Just lose the dot (.) at the end of the expression and it's gonna be working, even with "1" or "a".

```
[a-zA-Z0-9_]+
```